# 301 redirect only if URI doesn't contain specific string

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a drupal website which has been split up to two separate websites, and now I need to setup some rewrite rules in order to drive traffic to the new site.

Original website looks like this:

```
http://www.website.com (frontpage)
http://www.website.com/web1/subpage1 (subpage)
http://www.website.com/web1/subpage2 (subpage)
http://www.website.com/subpage3 (subpage)
http://www.website.com/subpage4 (subpage)
```

All references to subpages that are not in the web1-category have been removed from the website, but the pages are still published and they still show up in Google.

What I need is a rewrite rule that redirects from "website.com" to the frontpage of "new-website.com" if the user tries to access a page that is not the frontpage and not in the web1-category.

I suppose a rewrite-rule checking for the string "web1" in the URI would be the answer to my problem, but unfortunately I have no idea how to write the syntax.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

EDIT:

My htaccess file with @zessx proposed solution:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-website.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web1
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ http://www.my-new-website.com [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 9):

This is what you need :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !web1

RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ http://new-website.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi samsamX

Thanks for the input, but unfortunately it is not working. 

When accessing http://www.website.com/web1/subpage the user is redirected to http://www.new-website.com/web1/subpage.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks again.

Comment: I just tried it, this code works. Is your htaccess in the root folder ?

Comment: Yes, the htaccess file is in the root folder. I guess it must be conflicting with Drupal's own rewrite rules.

Comment: I have tried to place the code almost everywhere in my htaccess file, but nothing seems to work. 
I've added the content of my htaccess file to my original question. Do you see anything in there that you suspect to be conflicting with the redirect code?

Comment: Are you sure there's `web1/subpage` in your final url (on new website) ? There's nothing here which can redirect elsewhere than on new website frontpage.

Comment: @zessx , if i may ask , how should look a htaccess syntax to check if the url is as www.example.com or as www.example.com/file.php , and if is not it redirect to www.example.com

Answer (score 2):

A colleague of mine, found a solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web1(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteRule ^([\w/]*)$ http://www.new-website.com [L]`
```