# Add www to domain but not for an specific domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've the following code in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The code above is for add `www` in the domain if it does not have the `www`, but I've a domain like: myloadbalancername-432566808.us-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com (DNS from AWS Elastic Load Balancer) and this domain does not work with `www`, so, how can I do to add `www` for all domain requests, except for the specific domain?

**Update**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myloadbalancername
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I tried with the code above, to check if domain name does not have the word, so, if not have, check if domain does not have the `www` but without success. I'm beginner with `.htaccess` so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [301 redirect only if URI doesn't contain specific string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844155/301-redirect-only-if-uri-doesnt-contain-specific-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !myloadbalancername
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Because host name is not part of `%{REQUEST_URI}`